# How to solve this integral from Berkeley Tournament?

Tags: calculus, integration

From Berkeley University Math Tournament, its official site: https://bmt.berkeley.edu/archive, where you can find all the questions and answers.

Q20. A certain type of Bessel function has the form $I\left( x \right) =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{x\cos \theta}\mathrm{d}\theta}$ for all real $x$.

Compute $\int_0^{\infty}{xI\left( 2x \right) \mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x} = e/2$.

I do not know how to solve this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer.
The below is my attempt:
But the answer is already there in :
[Different ways to evaluate $\int_0^\infty xI_0(2x)e^{-x^2}\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162953/different-ways-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-xi-02xe-x2-dx?rq=1)

$$\int I(2x) x e^{-x^2} dx =1/\pi \int \int e^{2\ x\  cos(\theta)} d\theta \times x e^{-x^2} dx$$
$$ = 1/\pi \int  \int e^{2 \ x  \ cos(\theta)} \times x e^{-x^2} dx  d\theta $$
$$ = 1/\pi \int  \int e^{cos^2(\theta)} \times x e^{-(x-cos(\theta))^2} dx  d\theta $$
$$ = 1/\pi \int   e^{cos^2(\theta)} \times \left( \int x e^{-(x-cos(\theta))^2} dx \right)  d\theta $$

You need to evaluate:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-(x-cos(\theta))^2} dx$$  $$ = \int_{0}^{\infty} (x-cos(\theta)) e^{-(x-cos(\theta))^2} dx  + cos(\theta) \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(x-cos(\theta))^2} dx $$ $$= 0.5 \times \int_{cos^2(\theta)}^{\infty}  e^{-y} dy + cos(\theta) \int_{-cos(\theta)}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} du $$ $$= 0.5 \times e^{-cos^2(\theta)} + cos(\theta) \int_{-cos(\theta)}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} du $$
$y = (x-cos(\theta))^2$, $u = x-cos(\theta)$

First term contributes : $1/2$. Need to prove:
$$1/\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{cos^2(\theta)} cos(\theta) \int_{-cos(\theta)}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} du  = 0.5(e-1)$$